# AWS ALB and Lambda - [ERROR] KeyError: 'http-method'

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

I am working in AWS creating Lambda function and i am invoking it via API Gateway.
As many before me i reached that point where the function runs longer than 30 seconds and now the API Gateway is returning time out error.

I looked at workarounds and many suggest using ALB to run longer lambda functions. I started by creating my ALB and initially it works almost as expected. I am missing lambda response status code.
The main issue i have is that when running the lambda via ALB the events are not passed correctly it seems. I get "**[ERROR] KeyError: 'http-method'**" when i try

```
method = event['http-method']
```

When i call the Lambda via the API Gateway it works, but via ALB i get 502 Bad Gateway.

Hoping for further advise.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, just found out that ALB event is 'httpMethod' instead of 'http-method' as in the API Gateway.. Why not keep it the same?!